# configureRouter not called on compose view models

Tags: aurelia

It seems configureRouter is not called when using compose binding.

This is the View:

```
<template>
    <compose view="./ask-banner.html" view-model="./ask-banner"></compose>
...
```

In the parent, configureRouter is called as expected.  But in ask-banner.js, configureRouter is never called.

The issue is that I need a reference to the router so I can call the navigate method.

The activate method is called, so it seems like the configureRouter should be called as well.

Comment: I would not recommend putting a router on a composed element. Your router structure ought to follow a very linear path, e.g., a router view-model has a route with a child router view-model, and the nature of composes is non-linear, e.g., you have composed in three different elements into one page.

Comment: Good point @MatthewJamesDavis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a different way to get a reference to the router:

```
import {inject, singleton} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';
import {Router} from 'aurelia-router';
@inject(Router)
@singleton()
export class Ask{
constructor(router)
{
    this.router = router;
}
}
```